# wrong splitting content when writing to a file in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have an input .txt file which is converted from a pdf.
 I also have 50 outline words (keywords) which are generally known to be in the input file.
For each of the 50 outline words, I created  one output file and my purpose is to split the  input .txt file's content by writing it out to the relevant output file(s), according to the outline words found in the input.

The outline words can be found throughout the text, but we specifically target 'titles' which are identified by the fact that they contain the outline word preceded and followed by a newline character. I use regular expression, for example for the first outline word:

```
t = re.search("\nAbduction\n",content, re.I)
```

But I have 49 more like this for each of the possible titles. As i know this `t` may not return a value so what should I do for it to return a value for all of the possible titles? 
2nd question: When a particular title is identified, I need to output the text that follows to the corresponding output file, until another title is found (or EOF).  How can I do that ?

Any help is welcome.

**[Edit]** The text of this question was significantly reworded, restructured.  Apologies for such heavy editing; it it typically better to stay close to original text, but in this instance it appeared helpful to have an heavier hand...   Do check the previous version [or revert the edit] if you think otherwise!

**[re-edit]** (from text OP posted as an answer)
A sample of .txt file is like that :

```
Abduction 

Deﬁnition
Abduction is a form of reasoning , sometimes described
as “deduction in reverse,” Abduction whereby given a rule that
“A follows from B” and the observed result of “A” we
infer the condition “B” of the rule. More generally,
given a theory, T , modeling a domain of interest and
an observation, “A,” we infer a hypothesis “B” such that

Accuracy

Deﬁnition
Accuracy refers to a measure of the degree to which the
predictions of a (cid:55)model match the reality being mod.
```

It's going like to the end of the file with including 50 titles. I already created the files for each of the title names.I wrote a function like ;

```
def TextBetween(self, s, leader, trailer):
    end_of_leader = s.index(leader) + len(leader)
    if trailer == " ":
        return s[end_of_leader:]
    else :
        start_of_trailer = s.index(trailer, end_of_leader)
        return s[end_of_leader:start_of_trailer]
```

This calculates the content between leader and trailer ,so the problem is When i decide the leader and trailer i want to use blank space to find the correct title.Because of that i use regex which i mentioned in my question.I created 50 regex for each of the title and want to use them when writing to the files but i dont know how i achieve that.

Comment: Please be more clear as to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

While your question would be clearer if you posted a sample of the input.txt file, this code might be what you're trying to do:

```
keywords = ["Abduction", "Foobar"]
inf = open("infile.txt")
outf = None
for l in inf:
    if l[:-1] in keywords:
        if outf != None:
            outf.close()
        outf = open(l[:-1] + ".txt", "w")
    elif outf != None:
        outf.write(l)
```

This would create one file for each section of the document, named after the keyword that precedes it. So if I'm interpreting you correctly and the file looks like

```
Abduction
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Foobar
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
```

You will end up with two output files, one called Abduction.txt and one called Foobar.txt, each with the corresponding section of text. I'm sure your particular application will require more work but this should get you on the right track.